# Create a Record in Heroku Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just pushed my rails app to heroku, I actually have some fake data locally that I directly inserted into my table through rails console.

What is the equivalent of that in heroku, the tables are configured on heroku but there is no data.

I don't want to create a seed.rb in my db and then push it to github and then run rake db seed on heroku

can i do it manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enter your application console on heroku with:

```
heroku run rails console
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [gem](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps). It is all ready dependency for heroku gem. With it bundled in your app you can do stuff like:

```
heroku db:pull
heroku db:push
```

Commands are quite self explanatory.